# PHP choosing non zero variable randomly

Tags: php

Say I have 5 variables:

```
$a=2
$b=0
$c=7
$d=0
$e=3
```

I want to choose one variable randomly that is not zero, do something with it, then set that chosen variable to zero.

Note that I want to know which variable is chosen, for example if I got 7 I want to also know that it's $c, so that I can change its value after reading it.

What is the simplest way to do that?

I was thinking take all variables then randomize first, then check if it's zero, but it doesn't scale well if I had more variables and more zeroes.

Comment: will there always be fixed number of variables like you mentioned in your question ?

Comment: Yes there will be fixed number of variables.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend crafting an array that contains all of the target values. You can then filter the zero values out with **[`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter)**. Then select a random index from the filtered array with **[`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand)**.

You then have a random non-zero value assigned to `$filtered_array[$random_index]`, which you are free to assign to an independent variable, or echo out to the DOM.

```
<?php

$a = 2;
$b = 0;
$c = 7;
$d = 0;
$e = 3;

$array = [$a, $b, $c, $d, $e];
$filtered_array = array_filter($array);
$random_index = array_rand($filtered_array);

echo $filtered_array[$random_index]; // 2, 7 or 3
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/iVTCn)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: How do I know which variable is actually selected? since once I get the value I want to set this particular variable to zero.

Comment: You can set the variable equal to `0` by assigning it to an independent variable and then setting it `0` manually with `$var = 0`. However, to get it back in the **original** array, it's a little tricky, as the filtered array would give it a different index. In **that** case, I'd recommend running `array_rand()` **first**, then checking whether it's equal to `0`: `$random_index = array_rand($array); if ($random_index === 0) {}`. If it's not equal, I'd try picking another variable. I don't think you'd be able to avoid the scaling issue you were talking about in such a case unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a=2;
$b=0;
$c=7;
$d=0;
$e=3;
 $array = array($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);
 $array = array_filter($array, function($a) { return ($a !== 0); });

 echo $array[array_rand($array)];
```

Answer (score 1):

apply recursive function

```
function rand_not_zero($arr) {
    $rand_key = array_rand($arr);
    $result = $arr[$rand_key];
    if (!$result)
        $result = rand_not_zero($arr);

    return $result;
}

$array = array($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);
echo rand_not_zero($array);
```